# Side by side editing of richtext content in a webapp with quilljs or slatejs

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, quill, slatejs

I'd like to create a tool for my users on my website where they can annotate rich text in a splitscreen fashion:
Left is the rich text, loaded before hand that stays untouched.
Right is the annotation on the text ( image, comment).
Both panel are obviously synced when user scrolls down.

The idea and implementation seems like something that would be available out of the box in a wysiwyg (What you see is what you get) javascript library.

I'm trying to fiddle with the quilljs or slatejs libraries to have the desired result, but they seems to require extensive coding and customization.

I'm prepared to build this, but I have the feeling I'm not the first to do this kind of tool. This feels much too complicated for a obviously useful functionality.

Is there some open source javascript library, plug-in with this parallel editing feature or Am I thinking about this the wrong way ?